# Scala download stream not properly closed under Windows OS

Tags: scala, file, download, stream

I'm writing Scala code to download files from the internet. My approach looks like this:

```
case object Downloader {
    def download(): Path = {
        val url = new URL("https://some.valid.url/file.ext")
        val downloadFile = Paths.get("/some/valid/path/file.ext").toFile
        downloadFile.createNewFile()

        url #> downloadFile !!
    }
}
```

This piece of code works perfectly on my Ubuntu machine, but not on my Windows machine.
Apparently the Windows OS does not close the downloaded file, therefore further access is not possible.

I would appreciate, if somebody of you could shed some light on if this is a Scala or Windows issue and hopefully have some suggestion on how to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't handling your resources appropriately, you should ensure they are closed.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I supposed to be the cause, too. Could you give me a little hint on how to do so? The ```downloadFile``` is obviously only a simple "reference" to where to find the actual resource.

Comment: Are you familiar with Input and Output streams in java? If not, search for that.